# PostgreSQL calculate total execution time for query and triggers under load insertions

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to measure the total time consumed by PostgresSQL to execute a series of triggers.

In short words, the system is a python program who used the DB to store and calculate the shortest path using some plugins installed in postgresql. The system depends on triggers which called once a request is inserted in the request table.

```
   for i in range(50):
        readyhostslist = random.sample(allhosts, 100)
        fid = 0
        fw = 0
        hostlistready = {}
        for n in xrange(0,len(readyhostslist), 2):
            hostlistready[readyhostslist[n][0]] = readyhostslist[n+1][0]
        for src, dst in hostlistready.iteritems():
            try:
                # get next flow id

                #print src, dst
                self.db.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM rm;")
                fid = len(self.db.cursor.fetchall()) + 1
                self.db.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tracktime (fid) VALUES ({0} )".format(fid))
                self.db.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rm (fid, src, dst) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2});".format(fid, src, dst))
                self.db.cursor.execute("UPDATE rm set FW = {0} where fid = {1};".format(fw, fid))
                self.db._conn.commit()
            except Exception, e:
                print "Failure: flow not installed --", e
```

what I want to do is to know the total elapsed time from the moment I insert the request using python postgresql driver to the end where the results are stored in other table.

I tried the following but I failed. I start to insert current time before inserting the request and modify the last called trigger to update the end time.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tracktime CASCADE;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE tracktime (
       id      serial ,
       fid      integer,
       timestart timestamp default clock_timestamp(),
       timeend  timestamp ,
       waqtstart timestamp ,
       waqtend  timestamp ,
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS p_routing CASCADE;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE p_routing (
    counts    integer,
    status    text,
    PRIMARY key (counts)
);

CREATE TRIGGER run_routing_trigger
     AFTER INSERT ON p_routing
     FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE spv_constraint1_fun();

CREATE OR REPLACE RULE run_routing AS
    ON INSERT TO p_routing
    WHERE (NEW.status = 'on')
    DO ALSO (
         UPDATE p_routing SET status = 'off' WHERE counts = NEW.counts;
         );



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS p_{0} CASCADE;
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE p_{0} (
       counts integer,
       status text,
       PRIMARY key (counts)
);


CREATE OR REPLACE RULE run_{0} AS
    ON INSERT TO p_{0}
    WHERE (NEW.status = 'on')
    DO ALSO (
        DELETE FROM {1};
        UPDATE p_{0} SET status = 'off' WHERE counts = NEW.counts;
        );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION spv_constraint1_fun ()
RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
plpy.notice ("spv_constraint1_fun")
if TD["new"]["status"] == 'on':
    rm = plpy.execute ("SELECT * FROM rm_delta;")
    flowid = 0
    for t in rm:
        if t["isadd"] == 1:
            f = t["fid"]
            flowid = f
            s = t["src"]
            d = t["dst"]
            pv = plpy.execute("""SELECT array(SELECT id1 FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT 1 as id, sid as source, nid as target, 1.0::float8 as cost FROM tp WHERE isactive = 1',""" +str (s) + "," + str (d)  + ",FALSE, FALSE))""")[0]['array']
            plpy.execute ("UPDATE tracktime  SET timeend = clock_timestamp() where fid =" + str (flowid) +";")
            l = len (pv)
            plpy.execute ("INSERT INTO trackzeit (fid) VALUES(" + str (flowid) +");")
            for i in range (l):
                if i + 2 < l:
                    plpy.execute ("INSERT INTO cf (fid,pid,sid,nid) VALUES (" + str (f) + "," + str (pv[i]) + "," +str (pv[i+1]) +"," + str (pv[i+2])+  ");")
            plpy.execute ("UPDATE trackzeit  SET zeitend = clock_timestamp() where fid =" + str (flowid) +";")
        elif t["isadd"] == 0:
            f = t["fid"]
            plpy.execute ("DELETE FROM cf WHERE fid =" +str (f) +";")

    plpy.execute ("DELETE FROM rm_delta;")

return None;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpythonu' VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;


CREATE TRIGGER spv_constraint1
       AFTER INSERT ON p_spv
       FOR EACH ROW
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE spv_constraint1_fun();
```

while this works for individual requests, it doesn't when I try to loop and inserts 100  requests. What I observed is the python driver or the DB inserts the 100 requests then trigger the functions for each request.

p.s. I tried auto commit after each insertion statement in the python program and still got the same problem.

This is a quote from the results where you can see the cumulative or nearly cumulative(some other trials will have not this cumulative phenomena). Each line represents the total time measured using PostgreSQL functions associate with flow number (fid)

```
77.625
130.395
168.6
208.572
239.531
273.252
295.924
320.999
349.042
369.552
398.883
432.04
462.708
498.156
525.315
565.321
601.193
636.402
667.983
695.893
731.778
759.155
792.391
814.026
842.942
874.946
917.369
934.897
963.269
```

Comment: Add your code please

Comment: I tried to added what is really fits as I cant copy all code and database scripts here. Thanks @e4c5

Comment: yes, that's understandable. Can you add the trigger definition also if you don't mind.

Comment: and BTW, why do we have two queries here:  self.db.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO rm (fid, src, dst) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2});".format(fid, src, dst))
                self.db.cursor.execute("UPDATE rm set FW = {0} where fid = {1};".format(fw, fid))

Comment: I added more trigger codes and the function called at the end stage of path finding calculation. You can see that I log end time after the statment. and log other operations as well. the other logs work perfects but the first are not which are the routing finding. @e4c5 . regards

Comment: Hi, I am sorr to say your code has far too many issues. For example you are talking of triggers but you are actually using rules in many places and those rules appear to be dynamic sql. Some of those triggers/rules seem to fire of others. And in one trigger you are looping through a resultset and inserting into another table (something that can be replaced by INSERT INTO SELECT).

Comment: The idea is I want to measure its performance in execution time. This is not mine but for a system should be a reference to any upgrade made. any way to measure the execution time for those rules and functions with load insertion? @e4c5